# Algorithm for detecting overlaps

Tags: algorithms, efficiency, intervals, ordering

*This is a real-world application, not a student assignment.*

Suppose a list of events of that have `startTime` and `endTime`, and some overlap information. In pseudocode:

```
class Event {
    Time startTime;
    Time endTime;
    bool overlapsStart;
    bool overlapsEnd;
}
```

Events are considered overlaping if and only if their times intersect, but it's not considered overlap if some event just "touches" another (starts exactly when some other finishes).

There are two types of event: `NormalEvent` and `EmptyEvent`.

---

**What I want?**

For each event in the list, I want to:

1) Remove all `EmptyEvent`s that overlap another event of any type. In special, if some `EmptyEvent` overlaps another `EmptyEvent`, only one needs to be removed, so that the overlap ceases.

2) The `NormalEvent`s are first ordered by `startTime`, and then their booleans are set:

- `overlapsStart` is true if the event overlaps some event that comes **before** it.
- `overlapsEnd` is true if the event overlaps some event that comes **after** it.

---

**A trivial example:**

```
event1 = 6:00AM ➜ 8:00AM
```

and

```
event2 = 7:00AM ➜ 9:00AM
```

then:

```
event1.overlapsStart == false
event1.overlapsEnd == true

event2.overlapsStart == true
event2.overlapsEnd == false
```

**Another example:**

Now, this is what happens if some event "contains" another:

```
event1 = 6:00AM ➜ 9:00AM
```

and

```
event2 = 7:00AM ➜ 8:00AM
```

then, first event1 is put before event2, since it starts before. Then:

```
event1.overlapsStart == false
event1.overlapsEnd == true

event2.overlapsStart == true
event2.overlapsEnd == false
```

---

Naive implementation: I could analyze each event in turn, one by one, looking at all other events. That's easy, however this is too slow for a large number of events.

**My question:** What's an efficient way of solving this?

Comment: Hint: sort starting and ending times, then iterate with a counter, incr 1 if seen start, decrease 1 if seen end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want to delete as little EmptyEvents as possible.

In that case, you can achieve what you want in `O(nlog(n))` time, where `n` is the number of events.

Proceed as follows:

- First, get rid of the `EmptyEvents` which overlap with a `NormalEvent`. To do so, put all your starting and ending times in a vector and sort them in increasing order, breaking ties by putting end-times before start-times. Set a `counter = 0` and an empty unordered set `S`. Now go through your vector of times in order.

  - Each time you come across the start-time of an `EmptyEvent`, if `counter > 0`, then flag that event for deletion. If `counter == 0`, put that event (or rather its id) in `S`.
  - Each time you come across the end-time of an `EmptyEvent`, if `counter > 0`, then flag that event for deletion. Delete the corresponding event from `S` (if it is still in there).
  - Each time you come across the start-time of a `NormalEvent`, increase the `counter` by `1`.
  - Each time you come across the end-time of a `NormalEvent`, decrease the `counter` by `1`, flag all `EmptyEvents` in `S` for deletion and clear `S`.

  (then delete all the flagged events)
- Then, choose the largest subset of `EmptyEvents`, no two intersecting. To do so, sort all `EmptyEvents` according to end-time. Then just go through these events and greedily select one each time it doesn't intersect with the last selected one.
- Then, set all the `NormalEvent` booleans. Set a `counter = 0` and `prevStart` to track the most recent start-time. Sort all `NormalEvents` start and end-times. Iterate through them in order.

  - Each time you come across start-time of `NormalEvent` `e`, set `e.overlapsStart` to `counter > 0`. Then increase `counter` by `1`. Also set `prevStart = e.startTime`.
  - Each time you come across end-time of a `NormalEvent` `e`, decrease the `counter` by `1` and set `e.overlapsEnd` to `e.startTime < prevStart`.

I'll let you convince yourself of the validity of each step. But here is a good starting point if you are unable to do so :
[Interval scheduling on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_scheduling)

Answer (score 2):

@Tassle algorithm works great but needs more explaining for vectors ordering.

> To do so, put all your starting and ending times in a vector and sort
>   them in increasing order, breaking ties by putting end-times before
>   start-times. Set a counter = 0 and an empty unordered set S. Now go
>   through your vector of times in order.

The priority for the first vector ordering is:

```
Time
End-time over start-time
NormalEvent over EmptyEvent
```

> Then, set all the NormalEvent booleans. Set a counter = 0 and an empty
>   unordered set S of Events. Sort all NormalEvents start and end-times.
>   Iterate through them in order.

The priority for the second vector ordering is:

```
Time
Start-time over end-time
NormalEvents over EmptyEvent
```